# Are there new classes for replace ClassBuilder in JavaFX11

Tags: java, class, javafx, builder, openjdk-11

I'm migrating my application from `Java 1.7` to `Java 11`.
My application uses `JavaFX`.
During the migration, I see that classes like TooltipBuilder, GridPaneBuilder, CircleBuilder or TextBuilder are not existing anymore.
Can we find it in `JDK11` anyway?
What is the best thing to do to replace it ?

Comment: The builders were deprecated and mostly removed (except for a few internal implementations) due to problems with their design. What is your use case? How you were using them may dictate the best replacement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
I mostly use the create() and build() function, in order to create new instances, but I'm not sure to answer your question...

Comment: You should simply instantiate the objects via their constructors instead. You would then perform any necessary configuration, such as setting the font of a label, on the newly created instances.

Comment: Ok perfect ! Thank you very munch for the advice ! :)